# How to get frontend server IP address in ASP.NET Web API?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

Suppose I receive a request to my Web API from the client side (the server where the frontend is deployed). I need to get the IP address of the server.

The current solution is to use `HttpContext.Connection.RemoteIpAddress`, but this only gets the address of the user making the request.

Comment: That's not how it works. The client (browser) receives the HTML and JS from the front-end-server, and then it's the browser on the client's machine directly making the request to your API. If you have a different setup, explain how.

Comment: @CodeCaster So there is no way to get the address of the frontend server on the backend from the request, unless you pass it in every request as a header, right?

Comment: There are various ways, but I don't know why you think you need it.